# Query with casting in WHERE

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm learning this wonderful library, however while simple queries work, I'm confused how to write something that not in library FAQ.

For example,

```
create table if not exists ticks
(id bigserial not null constraint ticks_pkey primary key,
    timestamp timestamp not null
);
```

It it possible to write something like

```
select coalesce(max(id), 0) from ticks where timestamp::date = ?
```

Actually, I have 2 issues here

1. **column.max()** doesn't have any suitable modifiers, for example, **function()** accepts no parameters. Probably, I can emulate this in code after I fetch the row.
2. I have no idea how to make casting in **where** or write arbitrary **where** condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible to map object to your existing table then you could try something like:

```
object Ticks : LongIdTable() {
    val timestamp = datetime("timestamp ")
}

fun Expression<DateTime>.pgDate() = object : org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Function<DateTime>(DateColumnType(false)) {
    override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = queryBuilder {
        append(this@pgDate, "::date")
    }
}

val expr =  Coalesce(Ticks.id.max(), longLiteral(0))
Ticks.slice(expr).select {
    Ticks.timestamp.pgDate() eq DateTime.parse("2019-01-01")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've discovered that PostgreSQL supports CAST syntax as well, so I was able to use Column().castTo syntax.